# Print any object as a literal expression in python

Tags: python, printing, expression, literals, introspection

I want to print objects, so that the result is a valid python expression and can be used to reconstruct equivalent value.

Let's call this function `printexp`

For example,

```py
printexp(['a', 1+2, (True, {'f': [0]}, 1/2)])
```

would return

```py
"['a', 3, (True, {'f': [0]}, 0.5)]"
```

Comment: `printexp = lambda x: print(f'"{x}"')` ...?

Answer (score -1):

For objects only consisting of boolean, int, float, string, list, tuple, set, and dict, you can simply use builtin [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function.